# NodeJS - Wrong Express route being triggered

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, routes

I have the following routes available for a backend...

*admin.js*

```
router.get('/contents', ...);  // GET /admin/contents

router.get('/:adminID', ...);  // GET /admin/[adminID]

router.put('/:adminID', ...);  // PUT /admin/[adminID]

router.get('/', ...);  // GET /admin

router.post('/', ...);  // POST /admin
```

.. but in testing, the following:

```
PUT /admin/contents
```

triggers the `PUT /admin/[adminID]` route. But "contents" is not an ID. I understand why this is happening (i.e. it fits into the pattern), but I'm not sure what the best/common solution is to this? Ideally, I'd like it to recognize that "contents" is not an ID, and is in fact just attempting to use an unavailable endpoint.

I could use something like...

```
router.use('/contents', require('./admin-contents'));
```

but I'd prefer to limit each top-level endpoint to a single file, opposed to spreading it across so many.

Worst-case scenario, it will look for an admin with ID: "contents", and return "admin not found", but I'd prefer it to return 404, because that is not an available endpoint for `/admin`.

**Edit #1**

To clarify, `adminID` is a mix of letters and numbers, with either occurring in any position in the string. A regex will not work.

Also, the only route for `/admin/contents` is `GET`. Having to implement blank routes for all the other methods (`PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`, etc) is not ideal either.

Comment: `A regex will not work`. A regex will definitely work if adminId contains at least a number and a letter.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Yeah you're right. If you want to mod your answer below for a check like that (i.e. look for any numbers in a known-length ID string) I'll give you the gold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a `regex` after a paramenter name in the route, to avoid that scenario.

```
router.put('/:adminID(\\d+)', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.params.adminID); // I'm a number
});
```

Now `adminID` must be a number, otherwise it won't enter the route.

While that's not directly documented on `express` [routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), since express uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) we can see their documentation for this:

And it's documented in [Custom Matching Parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#custom-matching-parameters)

```
const regexpNumbers = pathToRegexp('/icon-:foo(\\d+).png')
// keys = [{ name: 'foo', ... }]

regexpNumbers.exec('/icon-123.png')
//=> ['/icon-123.png', '123']

regexpNumbers.exec('/icon-abc.png')
//=> null
```

**UPDATE**

> Your suggestion of checking for even just one number in a known-length
>   string should work,

```
app.put('/:adminID((?:\\w+(?<=\\d+)(?:\\w+)?))', (req, res) => {
   // I have at least 1 number
   // I can have or not alpha-numeric characters
   res.send(req.params.adminID);
});
```

The regex uses `Postive lookbehind assertions` which are supported without any flag since [Node.js 9.11.2](https://node.green/). So if you're using an older version, either upgrade or use the `--harmony` flag to run it.

Comment: IDs are strings, with numbers and letters

Comment: Then build the regex for your exact match, or provide a full example in your question. Nevertheless, this is the solution you're looking for. I'm giving you the tools.

Comment: So, care to give us an example of an ID you need to match?

Comment: Think of them like YouTube links. A string, x-characters long, where any character can be any digit or letter (upper and lower). Technically, the ID could be a real x-character string used for a route, but that's unlikely

Comment: So it could be: `aaa` `bb22` `bAc2` or `2222` there's no pattern at all?. If it could be a x-character string used for a route, you may have conflicts, and your routes are wrong.

Comment: I will take steps to make sure that they wouldn't be actual routes. Your suggestion of checking for even just one number in a known-length string should work, as you've said it would.

Comment: is the ID always the same length? If so provide that length

Comment: Currently unknown, still working on defining the routes before I move forward

Comment: Thanks for all your effort and time and doubling-down. This should work as intended!

Comment: You're welcome :), if you want to enforce a more strict ID, you can later change the regex, or in the same route do some extra validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that node interprets handlers in order:

```js
app.put('/admin/contents',  (req, res) => res.send('contents'))
app.put('/admin/:adminId',  (req, res) => res.send('id'))
```

When you enter `admin/contents`, **contents** is returned, for any other url `admin/whatever` **id** is returned.

Comment: But `PUT /admin/contents` isn't a route that I need. For `/admin/contents`, there is only a `GET` route. The way you've suggested means that I'd need to include `PUT` and `POST` and `PATCH` and so on, all the way down the list

Comment: What is wrong in `router.get('/admin/contents', ...); router.get('/admin/:adminID', ...);` then?

Comment: This is just one more step towards preventing unwanted behaviour. `/admin/contents` is a route, just not for the `PUT` method. I want to make sure that unavailable methods are identified as such, so I can return the correct error. Returning "unavailable endpoint" would be more informative (and more correct) than "unavailable admin ID". The latter might be particularly confusing, when someone is trying to figure-out what ID the error is talking about.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I think you should rethink your API to be more resource oriented - `/admin/admins/userId` should be responsible for admins management and `/admin/contents` should serve content resource.

Comment: You can also create the following order of handlers: 1. `get('/admin/contents', ...)` 2. `all('/admin/contents',(req, res) => res.status(404).send('Not found'))` 3. `//rest of handlers` - you need of course handle 404 manually but you are free from crazy and hard to maintain regex.

Comment: Oh! This is pretty slick! Hmmm. One thing that I always get hung-up on is "which way is the *best* way?" and then I'm stuck in this rut where I can't proceed until I make a decision.

Comment: What about *only* using `all('/contents', (req, res, next) => {...})` and then just checking the HTTP method within there? Is there any reason why that'd be taboo?

Comment: `"which way is the best way?"` - well... it depends ;) for me readability, cost of maintenance and simplicity are main factors.

Comment: `"What about only using all(...)"` - it also could be the solution, but it is not such straightforward - you need to look into handler implementation to figure out what's going on.